# Difference between a PDF and PMF

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

What is the difference between a probability density function and a probability mass function?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Probability density function vs. probability mass function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23293/probability-density-function-vs-probability-mass-function)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One is for discrete variables, the other for continuous.

They are also interpreted differently. The PDF is a probability *density*. If f(x) is a PDF, f(x) doesn't tell you the probability of getting x (In fact, the probability of getting precisely x is 0).
The way you use a PDF is through integration. So, the probability of getting a value that is in a dx area around x is approximately f(x)*dx.

Comment: why is it approximate? What is an exact value? $f(x)dx + o(dx^2)$?

Comment: Can discrete random variables can be treated as continuous (and thus be described by a PDF as well)?

Answer (score 3):

To be precise, a probability mass is a probability distribution. However, it is not a probability density - probability masses are discrete, while probability densities are continuous.

Comment: So the only difference is that a PDF is continuous?

Comment: More or less. Keep in mind that the discrete-ness of a PMF gives rise to some other differences. For example, the value of a PMF for an element of the sample space is a probability, while we must integrate the PDF to obtain a probability.