# Is it justifiable to call the probability mass function by the name “discrete probability density function”?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, terminology, density-function

Commonly, the [probability density function (PDF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function) is used when dealing with continuous random variables, while the [probability mass function (PMF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_mass_function) is used for discrete random variables.

This is the reason they are called “density function” and “mass function” respectively.

However, my professor would talk about a “continuous PDF” and a “discrete PDF”, instead of a PDF and PMF.

It seems that my professor is not the only one to use the term “discrete probability density function”. It is also used in [these UBC lecture notes](http://blogs.ubc.ca/math105/discrete-random-variables/the-discrete-probability-distribution/).

**Is it correct to call the probability mass function by the name “discrete probability density function”?**

Comment: Sorry but I fail to understand the question: if your teacher is precise about the meaning of "discrete pdf" (and it seems they are), what is the problem? If you want to be extra rigorous note that the PMF **is** a density, only with respect to the counting measure instead of the Lebesgue measure.

Comment: @Did This comment answered my question. Since it is a density with respect to the counting measure, then it's justifiable to call it a density function

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Probability density function vs. probability mass function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23293/probability-density-function-vs-probability-mass-function)

Comment: @user No, I'm asking about the term "discrete probability density function".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X$ be a discrete random variable with probability mass function $p_X : \mathcal{X} \to [0,1]$, where $\mathcal{X}$ is a discrete set (possibly countably infinite). Random variable $X$ can be *thought* of as a continuous random variable with the following probability density function

$$f_X (x) = \sum_{x_k \in \mathcal{X}} p_X  (x_k) \, \delta (x - x_k)$$

where $\delta$ is the Dirac delta. One could call $f_X$ a discrete probability density function, as its support is a discrete set. However, do note that $f_X$ is a *generalized* function, not a proper function.

Comment: But then this would not be a probability mass function. I was asking whether the simple probability mass function could also be called by the name 'discrete probability density function'

Comment: Sorry but I fail to see the advantages of equalling a function (your LHS) with a measure (your RHS), only to declare right away that the function is actually a *generalized* function, that is, an object for which we have no definition except the fact that it is not a function... :-)

Comment: @Did If you want to compute the PDF of $Z = X + Y$, where $X,Y$ are independent, $X$ is discrete and $Y$ is continuous, then the PDF of $Z$ is the **convolution** of $f_X$ and $f_Y$, which is $$f_Z (z) = \sum_{x_k \in \mathcal{X}} p_X  (x_k) \, f_Y (z - x_k)$$

Comment: Yes, the PDF of Z is then the function which is the convolution of the *distribution* of X (which is not a function, but a measure) with the PDF of Y (which is a function).

Comment: @Did Do you want me to replace "PDF" with "PD**G**F"?

Comment: (Sighs.) $ $ $ $