# Relation between mass function and probability density function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, density-function

Consider the entire population $\mathcal{P}$ of couples (including singles): let $\mathcal{M}$ denote the population of men, let $\mathcal{W}$ denote the population of women; an element of $\mathcal{P}$ can be $(m,w)$ if $m\in \mathcal{M}$ and $w\in \mathcal{W}$ are married, $(m,*)$ if $m\in \mathcal{M}$ is single, $(*,w)$ if $w\in \mathcal{W}$ is single.

Below I will distinguish the couples in $\mathcal{P}$ between **singles** and **matched couples**.

Suppose that the econometrician observes a certain characteristic $X$ of each matched couple. $X$ is treated as a continuous random variable with probability density function $h(\cdot)$.

I am confused between the definition of **mass function** (not to be mixed with *probability* mass function) and **probability density function**. Specifically, I found that
$$
\frac{\text{Mass of matched couples with $X=x$}}{\text{Mass of couples in the population (including singles)}}=h(x)
$$
Could you help me to clarify this relation? What is the definition of mass function and its relation with a pdf?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Probability density function vs. probability mass function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23293/probability-density-function-vs-probability-mass-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the definition of mass function and its relation with a pdf?

"Mass" is a measure of amount and, in this case, that is *most likely* just the count since there is no indication that any couple has any more "weight" than any other.   Well, not in your quote, anyway, although perhaps it is mentioned *elsewhere* that matched couples are counted as twice much as a single, or some such.

> Specifically, I found that
>   $$
> \frac{\text{Mass of matched couples with $X=x$}}{\text{Mass of couples in the population (including singles)}}=h(x)
> $$

Well, no.   If $X$ actually is a continuous random variable, then its probability density function will not exactly equal the ratio of sample masses.   However, if there is a mass of couples whose $X$ quality is approximately $x$ (within some degree of precision) then you have an *estimation* for the probability density function.

$$\widehat h(x)=\frac{\text{Mass of matched couples with $X\approx x$}}{\text{Mass of couples in the population (including singles)}}$$

Comment: Thanks. But, if "mass" means "number", $\frac{\text{Mass of matched couples with $X\approx x$}}{\text{Mass of couples in the population}}\in [0,1]$, while instead $h(x)\in \mathbb{R}$ in principle. How can that be a good estimator?